# How to Convert Currency to Words using Humanizer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, humanizer

I need to use the Nuget package Humanizer to convert currency to English words equivalent as follows

```
 using Humanizer;

 AmountInWords = pmt.Amount.ToWords()
```

pmt.Amount is of type decimal and it represents the amount in figures

I get the following error

```
Error   CS1929  'decimal' does not contain a definition for 'ToWords' and the best extension method overload 'NumberToWordsExtension.ToWords(int, CultureInfo)' requires a receiver of type 'int'
```

I have checked the documentation at the following url and I am not yet able to find a way to resolve it

```
https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#number-to-words
```

I will appreciate any guide to resolve this.

Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer/blob/60822b6ddbfef1097feb873fd0161dc812576fce/src/Humanizer/NumberToWordsExtension.cs - you will have to use int or long

Comment: I guess you'll have to humanize full Currency and fractional Currency separately. So for example "$35,70" become "Thirtyfive Dollars and seventy Cents".

Comment: That would mean having to split the figure and humanizing the two parts separately. That is actually what I am planning to do if no other solution comes up here. But I wish there could be a better way

Comment: Do you want such a conversion? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334034/convert-number-with-decimals-in-currency-to-words

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see Humanizer doesn't have a built in solution to this. I did come across this GitHub project that someone posted that you might look at. It seems the suggestion of splitting into two numbers is the right approach.

https://github.com/tiagonmas/ConvertCurrencyToText

Answer (score -1):

Since, **'decimal'** format does not contain a definition for **'ToWords'** so it requires a receiver of type **'int'**. So convert it into **'Int'** then Try.

```
    using Humanizer;
    
    AmountInWords = Convert.ToInt64(pmt.Amount).ToWords()
```

Thanks & Regards

Priyadharshini Charles